# Inheritance mapping with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, oop, jpa, seam

This is a fairly lengthy (not overly complex) design question so please bear with me. I'm trying to implement a person/role management system with POJOs and JPA. I'm fairly new to ORM and this is mostly a mapping problem.

I've got this working as POJOs and am comfortable with the caller-level API, but would now like to map it to a database using JPA or Hibernate in a Seam environment.

My implementation is based on the Decorator (GoF) and Person Role Object patterns (Baumer/Riehle et al). All roles are hard-coded and run-time addition of new roles is not supported since it would require code changes to extend behavior. I'd use user groups to implement security and permissions.

There is a Person interface with role management methods such as addRole(), removeRole(), hasRole(), getRole(), getRoles(), among other things. The concrete implementation is provided by a PersonImpl class.

There is an abstract class Role which also implements the Person interface (for decorator substitution equivalence), and a RoleImpl class that extends it. The Role class holds a reference to a person instance, using it to service any method / property calls on the person interface, meaning all subclasses of Role can handle the Person interface. The role constructor takes the person object as a parameter.

These are the interfaces/classes:

```
public interface Person {
    public String getFirstName();

    public void setFirstName(String firstName);
    .
    .
    .
    public boolean isEnabled();
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled);
    public Set<Role> getRoles();
    public Role addRole(Class<? extends Role> roleType);
    public void removeRole(Class<? extends Role> roleType);
    public boolean hasRole(Class<? extends Role> roleType);
    public Role getRole(Class<? extends Role> roleType);

    public enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE, UNKNOWN};
}

public class PersonImpl implements Person {
    .
    .
    .
}

public abstract class Role implements Person {
protected PersonImpl person;

    @Transient
    protected abstract String getRoleName();
    protected Role() {}
    public Role(PersonImpl person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return person.getFirstName();
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        person.setFirstName(firstName);
    }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return person.getRoles();
    }
    public Role addRole(Class<? extends Role> roleType) {
        return person.addRole(roleType);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

public abstract class RoleImpl extends Role {
    private String roleName;

    protected RoleImpl() {}

    public RoleImpl(PersonImpl person) {
        super(person);
    }
    . 
    . 
    .
}

public class Employee extends RoleImpl {
    private Date joiningDate;
    private Date leavingDate;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(PersonImpl person) {
        super(person);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This diagram shows the class relationships:

[image]

(If you can't see the diagram inline, view it here [via yUML](https://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy;dir:lr;scale:80/class/%5BPerson;%3C%3Cinterface%3E%3E%5D%5E-.-%5BPersonImpl%5D,%20%5BPerson;%3C%3Cinterface%3E%3E%5D%5E-.-%5BRole;%3C%3Cabstract%3E%3E%5D,%20%5BRole;%3C%3Cabstract%3E%3E%5D%5E-%5BRoleImpl%5D,%20%5BPersonImpl%5D%3C%3E-%3E%5BRoleImpl%5D,%20%5BPersonImpl%5D%3C-%5BRoleImpl%5D,%20%5BRoleImpl%5D%5E-%5BEmployee%5D,%20%5BEmployee%5D%5E-%5BTeacher%5D,%20%5BEmployee%5D%5E-%5BPrincipal%5D,%20%5BEmployee%5D%5E-%5BAccountant%5D,%20%5BRoleImpl%5D%5E-%5BParent%5D,%20%5BRoleImpl%5D%5E-%5BStudent%5D))

I'd use these classes like so:

```
Person p = new Person("Doe", "John", Person.MALE, ...);
// assuming Employee extends Role
Employee e = (Employee)p.addRole(Employee.class);
```

Since the Role class also implements the Person interface, I can also do:

```
// assuming Parent extends Role
Parent parent = new Parent((PersonImpl)p);

e.addRole(Parent.class);
e.getDateOfBirth();  // handled by the decorated person class

// assuming Manager extends Employee extends Role
Manager m = (Manager)p.getRole(Manager);

if (m.hasRole(Employee.class) { 
    // true since Manager derives from Employee
}
```

The questions I have are:

(a) Is this implementation needlessly complex and if so what would be a simpler approach? Note that this goes into a non-trivial business application and not a kiddy project, and I think the role subclassing is important to leverage behavior in cases such as Employee, Manager, etc.

(b) How do I map this in JPA/Hibernate?

(c) Can it be mapped so I can also take advantage of Seam Identity Management? (My definition of Role is clearly not analogous to Seam's)

(d) If I go with a table-per-subclass (InheritanceType.JOINED) mapping strategy, I map PersonImpl as PERSONS and RoleImpl as ROLES tables, and map each subclass of RoleImpl (such as Employee and Parent) to their own tables as EMPLOYEES and PARENTS.

I would then have a @ManyToMany relationship between PERSONS and ROLES (on the roles collection in PersonImpl), with the join-table PERSON_ROLES.

Now the problem is that the EMPLOYEES and PARENTS tables, etc. have only the ROLE_ID reference, since the inheritance mapping strategy obviously considers them to be extensions to Roles (ROLES) whereas I need them as addendum to PERSON_ROLES, and require the USER_ID + ROLE_ID key to be resolved properly, or at least the USER_ID.

I would prefer a normalized database with the attendant reliance on extra joins than a denormalized database which will be difficult to maintain and likely bunch up a ton of unused and irrelevant fields, which is why I think table-per-subclass is the way to go.

Or is a table-per-class-hierarchy (InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)  with a discriminator column OK (from database maintenance perspective) in this scenario? Note that some roles are likely to have dozens of properties/fields.

(e) Is there a better alternative to this design?

Would very much appreciate any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: If each role object applies to a single person object, as your code implies, then why is there a @ManyToMany relationship between PERSONS and ROLES? Isn't it @OneToMany?

Comment: One person may have multiple roles. Each role may have multiple persons. I think Arthur's point of @OneToMany on one side and @ManyToOne on the other may have some merit. Have to check...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said

> So please bear with me

So my answer will be based on what you said

> All roles are hard-coded... There is an abstract class Role...

If There is an AbstractRole class, so i suppose some properties defined in AbstractRole class **are inherited by all of subclasses**

```
@Entity
/**
  * Which strategy should we use ??? keep reading
  */
@Inheritance
public abstract class AbstractRole implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private String commonProperty;
    private String otherCommonProperty;
    private String anotherCommonProperty;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    // getter's and setter's

}
```

Now Employee (Same approach used by Parent and Student)

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractRole {

    private String specificEmployeeProperty;

    // getter's and setter's

}
```

But which inheritance strategy To use ???

**InheritanceType.JOINED**

- Subclasses have a complex mapping: many properties, other relationships as @OneToMany, @OneToOne, @ManyToMany and so on
- If you use Hibernate as JPA provider, keep in mind it does not support discriminator column. See [here](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/ANN-140)
- A simple query will UNION ALL all of Table defined for each subclass. Maybe you just want to retrieve just one subclass and you will see performance issues. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700680) goes an workaround.

**InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE**

- Subclasses have a simple mapping. Not so many properties and minimal amount of other relationships
- resolution of concrete class at runtime
- It deals with a lot of nullable columns once all of subclasses share The same Table
- Faster performance

Now let's see

> There is a Person with role management methods such as addRole(), removeRole(), hasRole(), getRole(), getRoles(), among other things

Well, if i see something like *addRole* method, i suppose Person has Either @OneToMany or @ManyToMany relationship with AbstractRole class. I know, i know... You have @ManyToMany relationship but **i really advice** you split your @ManyToMany into @OneToMany - @ManyToOne relationship. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212058/how-to-make-a-composite-primary-key-java-persistence-annotation/1252317#1252317) how To

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private List<AbstractRole> roleList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @OneToMany
    public List<AbstractRole> getRoleList() {
        return this.roleList; 
    }

    // getter's and setter's

}
```

And finally

> Can it be mapped so I can also take advantage of Seam Identity Management

Seam Identity Management **allows you implement your own behavior regardless of using JPA or not**.

```
@Name("authenticationManager")
public class AuthenticationManager {

   /**
     * Starting with Seam 2.1+, you should use Credentials instead of Identity
     * To collect your username and password
     *
     * Your JSF Form should looks like
     *
     * <h:inputText value="#{credentials.username}"/>
     * <h:inputSecret value="#{credentials.password}"/>
     */
    private @In org.jboss.seam.security.Credentials credentials;

    /**
      * Login method
      *     must take no arguments
      *     must return a boolean indicating whether the credentials could be verified
      *
      * method name does not mind
      */
    public boolean authenticate() {
        /**
          * Logic To verify whether credentials is valid goes here
          */
    }

}
```

And define your authenticate-method in */WEB-INF/components.xml*

```
<security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticationManager.authenticate}"/>
```

About your mapping It depends on business requirement, customer needs and so on... but I Think it can be simpler as shown above

Good lucky!

Comment: I've added code snippets showing my interface/class definitions. You are right in assuming that there is a collection for Roles in Person.

Will go through your response in detail before reverting. Thanks.

Comment: @alan-p See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443790/2468185#2468185 how we implement a similar scenario. A couple of notes: I would not use Person as a implemented interface by AbstractRole. I Think your model could be simpler. Why not To use Person as a simple POJO instead of using it as a interface ??? I understand you can have a complex person/role management system, but keep The code simpler. If possible, use domain-driven-design approach See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597219/2598168#2598168

Comment: I haven't gotten round to doing this fully but I think a lot of the points you raised are valid and have been helpful so I'm accepting this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @alan-p See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700680/3017146#3017146 how i implement inheritance by using MapedSuperClass annotation instead of default inheritance annotations.