# JPA: When to choose Multivalued Association vs. Element Collection Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I would like to better understand the differences between

(1) a traditional **Multivalued Relationship/Association**

```
   @Entity -> @OneToMany -> @Entity
```

and

(2) the JPA2 **Collection of Embeddable (and basic) Types**

```
  @Entity -> @ElementCollection -> @Embeddable
```

I see the syntactical differences, but wonder whether there are also *performance implications*.  Under the hood, the database implementation looks very similar.

Intuitively, I would typically use the `@ElementCollection` for *composition scenarios*.  But even that feels very similar like `CascadeType=DELETE`.

Am I missing the essence here?  Is one more efficient than the other for certain purposes?

Thank you, J.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Intuitively, I would typically use the @ElementCollection for composition scenarios. But even that feels very similar like CascadeType=DELETE

They are similar, with some slight differences. The [ElementCollection](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) page from the [Java Persistence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence) wikibook summarizes it pretty well:

> ### [Emdedded Collections](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Emdedded_Collections)
>
> An `ElementCollection` mapping can be
>   used to define a collection of
>   `Embeddable` objects. This is not a
>   typical usage of `Embeddable` objects as
>   the objects are not *embedded* in the
>   source object's table, but stored in a
>   separate collection table. This is
>   similar to a `OneToMany`, except the
>   target object is an `Embeddable` instead
>   of an `Entity`. This allows collections
>   of simple objects to be easily
>   defined, without requiring the simple
>   objects to define an `Id` or `ManyToOne`
>   inverse mapping. `ElementCollection` can
>   also override the mappings, or table
>   for their collection, so you can have
>   multiple entities reference the same
>   `Embeddable` class, but have each store
>   their dependent objects in a separate
>   table.
>
> The limitations of using an
>   `ElementCollection` instead of a
>   `OneToMany` is that the target objects
>   cannot be queried, persisted, merged
>   independently of their parent object.
>   They are strictly privately-owned
>   (dependent) objects, the same as an
>   `Embedded` mapping. Their is no `cascade`
>   option on an `ElementCollection`, the
>   target objects are always persisted,
>   merged, removed with their parent.
>   `ElementCollection` still can use a
>   fetch type and defaults to `LAZY` the
>   same as other collection mappings.

#### See also

- [Embeddables (Aggregates, Composite or Component Objects)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables)

Answer (score 8):

JPA specification is clear

> Embeddables cannot be queried, persisted, merged independently of their parent object. **They are strictly privately-owned (dependent) objects**

You should use **carefully** because its lifespan **is bounded by the lifespan of the owning entity instance.** So if you persist/merge/remove your owning entity instance, **all of its embeddables** instances will be persisted/merged/removed

Suppose you do something like

```
/**
  * Let's suppose owning contains SIX embeddables instances
  */
Owning owning = manager.find(Owining.class, owningId);
```

So your modify **just** your Owning entity at view layer and submit your changes. You retrieve your Owning entity by using

```
/**
  * Usually your web framework Takes care of binding your submitted data
  */
Owning owning = new Owning();
owning.setProperty(request.getParameter("property"));
```

Then you can merge your submitted data and **you Think** your embeddables instances **are stored in database** yet. Well, let's see

As shown above **you (or your web framework) just retrieved Owning properties**, right ??? So your owning.getElementList() **is empty**. Because owning.getElementList() is empty, **JPA will remove all of its embeddables instances**. Keep this in mind.

**Usually** an embeddable class does not have relationship with other than its Owning Entity. And when using a Set of embeddables, JPA **always** select before saving/updating because it needs to compare one by one **by using its equals method**. So you need a **consistent equals implementation** when using a Set collection.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029745/a-class-that-behaves-like-entity-and-embeddable) you can see its counterpart in Hibernate.

Comment: @Jan Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440806/uml-class-relationships/2441251#2441251 Take a look at **composition** and you will see where @ElementCollection fits better