# JPQL query - Entity contains a list of Longs

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpql

In my Spring MVC app (Hibernate version: 4.1.7.final) I have an entity with a list of longs, like the following one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "foo_numbers",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(
                    name = "foo_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Collection<Long> numbers;

    ...
}
```

The goal is to write a query for those Foos which list is empty or contains a given number, something like:

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Foo AS f WHERE f.numbers IS EMPTY OR (:num) MEMBER OF f.numbers")
Collection<Foo> findTheRightFoos(@Param("num") Long num);
```

But I experienced the following issues:

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Foo AS f WHERE (:num) MEMBER OF f.numbers")
Collection<Foo> findFoos_1(@Param("num") Long num);
//org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1
//Hibernate log: select fooba0_.id as id9_ from foo fooba0_ cross join foo_numbers numbers1_ where fooba0_.id=numbers1_.foo and (? in (.))

@Query("SELECT f FROM Foo AS f WHERE (:num) IN f.numbers")
Collection<Foo> findFoos_2(@Param("num") Long num);
//Can't start the app, got the following exception:
//antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected end of subtree ...
//... Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [SELECT c FROM com.acme.Foo AS f WHERE (:num) IN f.numbers]

@Query("SELECT f FROM Foo AS f WHERE f.numbers = (:num)")
Collection<Foo> findFoos_3(@Param("num") Long num);
//org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [3870] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [3870] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection]

@Query("SELECT f FROM Foo AS f WHERE f.numbers IS EMPTY")
Collection<Foo> findFoos_4();
//Can't start the app, got the following exception:
//antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected end of subtree ...
//... Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [SELECT c FROM com.acme.Foo AS f WHERE f.numbers IS EMPTY]

@Query("SELECT f FROM Foo AS f WHERE f.numbers IS NULL")
Collection<Foo> findFoos_5();
//org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'is null)' at line 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'is null)' at line 1
//Hibernate log: select fooba0_.id as id9_ from foo fooba0_ cross join foo_numbers numbers1_ where fooba0_.id=numbers1_.foo and (. is null)

@Query("SELECT f FROM Foo AS f WHERE f.numbers = NULL")
Collection<Foo> findFoos_6();
//org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'is null)' at line 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'is null)' at line 1
//Hibernate log same as 'findFoos_5': select fooba0_.id as id9_ from foo fooba0_ cross join foo_numbers numbers1_ where fooba0_.id=numbers1_.foo and (. is null)
```

What's wrong with that? How can I do that?

Comment: looks a lot like this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As guido mentioned, this was due to this bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6686

I've tried it and it definitely works now in Version 5.4.11

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the kind of query you desire (on the contents of an `@ElementCollection`) you will need to change to a `@OneToMany`  association. 
Here is my support (from [JPA: When to choose Multivalued Association vs. Element Collection Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418683/jpa-when-to-choose-multivalued-association-vs-element-collection-mapping) )

The limitations of using an `@ElementCollection` instead of a `@OneToMany` is that the target objects cannot be queried, persisted, merged independently of their parent object. They are strictly privately-owned (dependent) objects, the same as an `@Embedded` mapping. There is no cascade option on an `@ElementCollection`, the target objects are always persisted, merged, removed with their parent. `@ElementCollection` still can use a fetch type and defaults to LAZY the same as other collection mappings.