# Hibernate not deleting/updating one to many

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I am trying to learn how to work with hibernate, and until now i thought i was doing ok...
The problem is, i have a one to many relationship that i can't update/delete.
My DB is pretty basic, i have a ClientsBasic that has a one to many relationship with IndirectClients (which simply has a ClientsBasic ID and a URL, both keys because you can have for the same ID lots of URLs)

ClientBasic:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "clientsBasic", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<IndirectClients> getIndirectClients() {
        return this.indirectClients;
    }

    public void setIndirectClients(List<IndirectClients> indirectClients) {
//      this.indirectClients = indirectClients;
        this.indirectClients.clear();
        this.indirectClients.addAll(indirectClients);
    }
```

ClientDao:

```
public ClientsBasic save(ClientsBasic client) throws HibernateException {
    Transaction tx = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(client);
    tx.commit();
    log.info("Client saved with id: " + client.getClientId());

    return client;
}
```

Now if i try to delete ClientsBasic, it will delete both ClientsBasic and all related indirectClients, so its working as expected, but if i simply try to update/delete and entry in indirectClients it doesn't work.

Example:
I create a new Client

```
ClientsBasic cb = new ClientsBasic("company_1", 1234, "company_1@email.com");
cbDao.save(cb);
```

And then a new Indirect Client

```
List<IndirectClients> indirectClientsSet= new ArrayList<IndirectClients>();
indirectClientsSet.add(new IndirectClients(new IndirectClientsId(cb.getClientId(), "www.url.test_1.com"), cb));
cb.setIndirectClients(indirectClientsSet);
cbDao.save(cb);
```

Now if i try to change the url like this

```
ClientsBasic cb = cbDao.findClientById(1);
List<IndirectClients> indC = cb.getIndirectClients();   
indC.get(0).getId().setUrl("TEST");
cb.setIndirectClients(indC);
cbDao.save(cb);
```

no changes are made in the DB.

Can someone please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you configured any [TransactionManager](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Hibernate+Sessions+and+Transaction+Management+Guidelines) in your application?

Comment: @Genzotto I don't think so, its the first time i hear that. Do you advise on configuring one?

Comment: which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 4.2.1

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.0/reference/en-US/html/ogm-configuration.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `IndirectClients` is defined as an Entity it has its own life cycle, meaning you have to persist/delete instances separately from their `ClientBasic` parent.
If you want a scenario where all children are managed through their parent relation, consider using [ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html).

See also [JPA: When to choose Multivalued Association vs. Element Collection Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418683/jpa-when-to-choose-multivalued-association-vs-element-collection-mapping#3419734)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that. I've tried a little test and it worked! now i will have to study about ElementCollection so i don't have to delete it separately. 
Once again thank you!