# Class diagram: Can I share a composition?

Tags: c++, uml

Let's say I'm using the mvc pattern to make a simple game in c++ and have a world object whose lifetime is managed by a controller class. This feels clearly like a composition, but what if, say a game logic class needs a permanent reference to the same world as well, or environments to this world (who is owned by the world) needs references to it, are these just regular associations or should I make all shared aggregations?

What makes me confused is that composition is defined as 'unshared'. But does this mean not shared with any other relationship, or only not shared with other aggregations and compositions. Also, how is shared aggregation typically implementet in c++? I mean, someone must manage the lifetime. Now we can use shared_ptr, but without them are everything shared just created in main and passed (and destroyd) from there? Which leads me to wonder; is it wrong to model the controller in a class diagram, should only the model part be modelled?

As another example of my main question (are composites allowed to be shared with any other kind of relation in a uml class diagram) e.g. can a wheel on a car be shared with other objects? If the engine needs a permanent reference, how should it be modelled? A simple association?

Comment: Be careful. The Multi-View-***Controller*** pattern, as it was originally described, is pretty much dead nowadays. People strangely talk about it all the time, but when was the last time you saw an architecture with independent controllers that could be plugged into different views? The reality is that views and controllers have merged long since. What you really mean is to **separate the UI from the business logic**. That's by no means a bad thing, just a hint that "MVC" is mostly an technically inaccurate definition nowadays. You should seriously rethink your problem from the ground up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I should clarify that the game logic class is owned by the controller. I take it you mean that it's rare to be able to write controllers that can be reused. I merely see controllers as a mediator between the view and a model and needs to be rewritten when either of those changes.

Comment: @mshell: The chapter about MVC in "Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture" by Buschmann et al contains a good description and explains how modern GUI frameworks have turned classical MVC into what they call the "Document-View" pattern (pp 140-141). Practically, the "Controller" used to be the event handling, but today's toolkits strongly couple event handling and display. Your example sounds as if the so-called "controller" was merely kind of an easier-to-use interface for the game logic (a "Facade" in GoF terminology).

Comment: Think I need to look up that book. I've been a bit frustrated with how the description of mvc always seem to differ from implemententations. As far as my example goes it was kinda vague to illustrate my question. The "game logic" was merely a means by me to remove game rules from other data entities without cluttering the controller with it. The game logic has no direct connection to the controller (i'll maybe use observer pattern or similar). I have updated my question with another example

Comment: You are not alone. If you do some research on this topic on Google, you'll find that many developers share your frustration. MVC was probably a good idea back in the early 90s, but both today's desktop GUI frameworks *and* web UI development have rendered it obsolete (Buschmann et al's book is still quite old but they correctly observed this evolution already back then). The useful inheritage of MVC remains the importance of decoupling business logic from the rest of the application. (I'll see if I can actually answer your real question now :))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and one of the best example is that of a pool (the struture, not the one with water...). In a pool, the pool manager has a composition relationship with all the elements. The pool manager manages the allocation of elements to "users" as required. The users are now sharing these agregate elements.

It is important to note that the pool manager is the owner of the pool elements and is, therefore, responsible for their creation and destruction (as required to maintain the pool within prescribed limits) and needs to keep track of their allocation. The pool elements can also only have one owner. The pool's user can only borrow and return an element in this scenario.

In your scenario, I would suspect you can use either aggregations or just a simple association, keeping in mind that the owner of the object (the one with the composition) can destroy it...

Answer (score 0):

Taking your car-part of the question, if you mean if it is legal to use both white and black diamonds in the same picture like in this one..

[image]

..then I think it is perfectly valid and doable.

In my understanding the **black diamonds** just represent the **"ownership"**, saying who is responsible for releasing memory and chaining the **calls to destructors** and invalidating the other weak pointers (those coming from lines with white diamonds and lines without diamonds)

Another picture where both diamonds co-exist at the same time can be found at Kirill Fakhroutdinov's site under..

**EDIT: after @gwag comment**
 <del>http://www.uml-diagrams.org/library-domain-uml-class-diagram-example.html (see the `Library` class)</del>

..http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dicom-real-world-uml-class-diagram-example.html (see the `Visit` class)

Comment: Your understanding of composition is wrong. A composition is a special form of aggregation, where a component instance is part of at most one aggregate instance at a time (that is, it cannot be shared between several aggregates). See this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138247/uml-notation-aggregations-compositions-vs-vanilla-associations/25120476#25120476] to a related question.

Comment: @gwag yes I read wrong the Kirill's diagram, it does not support my argument. But I believe the UML specification backs me. See [UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF/), page 38 which says "..Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part instance be included **in at most one composite** at a time..". It does not disallow inclusion in shared aggregations, at least I don't know where it would do it and I don't see a reason why as it is a very common programming pattern

Answer (score -2):

Your main question ("are composites allowed to be shared with any other kind of relation in a uml class diagram") is not very well expressed. You probably refer to components and not to composites. Indeed, a wheel, as a part/component of a car, cannot be shared with other cars (at the same time), while an employee, as a part of a company or team, can be shared with several other companies or teams..

But this non-shareability concerns only the two classes involved in the composition relationship (Car and Wheel, Company and Employee). And it does not restrict component objects to participate in other relationships instantiating other associations.